# ImportError: cannot import name 'trange'

Tags: python-3.x, tqdm

I'm trying to use

```
from tqdm import trange
```

and I get the error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'trange'
```

I'm using Python 3.6.3 and just installed the newest packages. Any help on why trange isn't found?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by reisntalling with pip.